# Would you understand a 3rd state for a "like" action if it's using the same icon?

Tags: buttons, icons, actions

We're having a usability debate: would the user understand what the 3rd state means, without text or tooltips, if all he is presented with is an icon in different color, in a different component?

Could you guys please tell us, for each image, what the "like" state means for you?

## Scenario 1

[image: Scenario 1]

## Scenario 2

[image: Scenario 2]

## Scenario 3

[image: Scenario 3]

## Scenario 4

[image: Scenario 4]

Comment: Hi Maktouch and welcome! Your question is a good one, but your audience is not. Instead of asking UX professionals if they understand the icons within the context you should be asking this question of your target users. This simple test will give you exactly what you need to know for your product.

Comment: Hey @BenjaminS, thanks for your feedback. Usually, it's what I do, but in this case, it's for the MVP and we don't have any users yet (launching in a few weeks).. so I'm not sure what or where to ask.

Comment: This is a question better suited for a venue like UserTesting.com or some place like that. But for what it's worth, I have no idea what a 3rd state would do here. Liking is binary, either you have marked something as a "like" or you haven't.

Comment: Hey @NathanRabe, awesome site that you've linked. I've subscribed for the trial. Thanks for the feedback, it's exactly the kid of stuff we wanted/needed to hear.

Comment: Hi @Maktouch, it is always interesting to test ideas about new interactions and designs, but instead of asking for opinions (which doesn't fit in with the UXSE forum's goals), if you can provide some rationales and alternate design ideas that the community can evaluate then it will be a much more useful question in terms of getting responses back from the people here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to figure out how a third state would totally impact the context of liking here. As a user, I would initially assume that the like (or heart) icon insinuates an action, especially in this social scene. This affordance is more obvious with the outlined icon as seen in `scenario 1`

Answer (score 2):

Note: this started as a comment but was getting too long. Also, in hindsight, my answer is probably getting way off track with what you asked... sorry :)

---

I am going to guess that your 3 states mean: "none", "like" and "love". Where the yellow icon is used for "love" and the solid white is for "like". The empty one is very clear in that it means "none" and is not an issue in this question.

The problem however isn't in being able to work out what the different ones mean when presented with examples of all 3, the problem comes from not knowing that there is even a 3rd option to begin with.

I expect most users will see this as a toggle button and think to either click it or not. So we need to consider: how will the user know there is a 3rd option?

Well, it partially depends on how the user selects the 3rd option. I am going to take a stab in the dark and guess it's "click for like" and "hold for love". Assuming that is correct, let's look at how the user might work that out without being told.

1. The user might accidentally hold the button when they attempt to click it
2. The user might see a yellow heart on a post in another context. Perhaps via another person using the app, or from some promo media.
3. The user is used to other social application that allow different reactions by holding down the button.

Point 2 probably isn't going to be very common, so we can't rely on that.

Point 3 is starting to be used more commonly by apps and users are starting to expect something from a "long hold" action. These users are already trained, so you don't need to worry about them.

Point 1 isn't much better, but it's certainly more likely to happen. Also, we can make changes to the UI to help promote the ability to hold the button...

For example, when the user clicks the button have the icon start to grow in size. Even if they just click, have it grow a little before it become a like icon. Humans are pretty curious (and mischievous), when we see something start to grow we will think "oooh, how big can a make it grow" or "if I hold it long enough, will it break the UI". It won't take long before the user realise they just found how to do "yellow hearts".

For ideas, check Facebook Messenger app and how that provides feedback when you hold the like button.

An additional though: how much do you care if some of your users never even realise there is a 3rd option? Does it have any bearing on how the rest of the application works?

---

**Summary**: Instinctively it looks like a binary toggle, but there are lots of things you can do to help the user realise it isn't. So if you want the design to work, then you certainly can.